# How to handle two forms in one asp.net core view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, tag-helpers

I have two forms in one view, with one ViewModel, with two submission buttons included for everyone, with two independent actions for everyone.

**the problem**
when I submit either one of them this error appears

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
> AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints.
> Matches:
>
> DAS.Controllers.DocumentsController.CreateIn (DAS)
> DAS.Controllers.DocumentsController.CreateEx (DAS)

**The view**

```
// one ViewModel
@model VMCreateDoc

// First form to submit "CreateIn" action
<form asp-controller="Documents" asp-action="CreateIn" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 // bla bla bla
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Save In">
</form>

// Second form to submit "CreateEx" action
<form asp-controller="Documents" asp-action="CreateEx" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 // bla bla bla
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Save Ex">
</form>
```

**The actions**

```
    // DocumentInternal Included in the same ViewModel VMCreateDoc
    [HttpPost("FileUpload")]
    public IActionResult CreateIn(DocumentInternal documentIn, List<IFormFile> files)
    {
       // bla bla bla
       return View();
    }

    // DocumentExternal Included in the same ViewModel VMCreateDoc
    [HttpPost("FileUpload")]
    public IActionResult CreateEx(DocumentExternal documentEx, List<IFormFile> files)
    {
       // bla bla bla
       return View();
    }
```

**The view model**

```
public class VMCreateDoc
{
    public DocumentExternal DocEx { get; set; }
    public DocumentInternal DocIn { get; set; }
}
```

It seems every submission does submit for both forms. So, conflict takes place.    

what do you think this problem can be solved?

Comment: Doesn't `[HttpPost("FileUpload")]` specify that both `CreateIn` and `CreateEx` should appear as one action named `FileUpload` ? Looks like ASP.NET Core discovered this bug only when a request came and it couldn't decide which method to call

Comment: I suspect if you check the HTML source you'll see that both forms have the same `action`, `FileUpload`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Wow, that's right. when I changed the route name, the conflict has gone. Thank you so much. thank you all guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all guys who try to help me. and big thanks for Panagiotis Kanavos.
the problem was with the annotation above actions.
all I did is to change it and the problem got solved.

**like this**

```
// DocumentInternal Included in the same ViewModel VMCreateDoc
[HttpPost("documentIn")]
public IActionResult CreateIn(DocumentInternal documentIn, List<IFormFile> files)
{
   // bla bla bla
   return View();
}

// DocumentExternal Included in the same ViewModel VMCreateDoc
[HttpPost("documentEx")]
public IActionResult CreateEx(DocumentExternal documentEx, List<IFormFile> files)
{
   // bla bla bla
   return View();
}
```